# how to use cloudify to auto-heal/scale docker containers

Tags: docker, workflow, cloudify

In my project, I'm using cloudify to start and configure the docker containers. 
Now I'm wondering how to write YAML files to auto-heal/scale those containers.

My topology is like this: a Compute node contains a Docker-Container node, and in the latter runs several containers.

I've noticed cloudify does the job of auto-healing on the base of the Compute node. So **can't I trigger an auto-heal workflow by containers' statuses**?

And for auto-scale, I installed the monitor agent and configured the basic collectors. The CPU use percent seems not able to trigger the workflow. cloudify docs about [diamond plugin](http://docs.getcloudify.org/4.0.0/plugins/diamond/#collectors-config) mentions some built-in collectors. Unfortunately, I failed to figure out how to config the collectors.

In hope of some inspirations. Any opinions are appreciated. Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

The docker nodes should be in the right groups for scale and heal.
You can look at this example
[scale-heal example](https://github.com/cloudify-examples/nodecellar-auto-scale-auto-heal-blueprint/blob/master/openstack-blueprint.yaml#L267)

It does exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the example. I was trying to adopt the built-in policy types so I didn't pay enough attention to it. But by importing a clj resource, it turns out to work fine. You star!